# Elasticsearch: which documents include term?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform some text mining on my elasticsearh database, i.e. calculate correlation between certain terms, or document clustering.

What i need for that, is to know, which documents include certain term in given field.
For example, if I have these three documents:
"Head and shoulders"
"Knees and toes"
"Head or tail"
than I would like to have search for term "head" to return either true/false vector (true, false, true), or list of positions of documents with this term (1 and 3)

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks,
Zbynek

Comment: What about term filter ?

Comment: Documents aren't stored in any particular order in the Elasticsearch index.  You can get matching documents, but position doesn't make any sense.